# Apple ID Sign In stuck with Xcode 8.3.1 ( awa 8.3 & 8.2)

Tags: xcode

I'm brand new to the iOS development environment (previous just built in Expo XDE with React-Native). I'm running into an issue with Xcode where when I try to add an Account to Xcode, it just hangs after I enter my credentials and press sign in. It doesn't even seem to attempt to validate the credentials as I can enter the correct password or a wrong password and the activity indicator just continues to spin. I'm then forced to force quit Xcode.

I've seem some similar issues but they at least get some response indication like "Apple Id or Password is incorrect" where as I get nothing but a loading indicator stuck spinning. I ensured that the MacBook has a Serial Number in "About this Mac". As well, I am able to successfully sign in with the Apple ID @ developer.apple.com.

I've uninstalled and installed 8.3.1 a couple times to no avail, tried 8.3 and 8.2 as well with no success and have restarted the MacBook itself. Nothing has worked.

*One caveat: I borrowed the MacBook from a friend but he has never used it in a developing capacity. I installed Xcode for the first time ever on his system. Figured this could possibly be related to the issue?

Any help would be great so I could finally get started building with Xcode!

Thanks!

Comment: You should be prompted whether you want to use the Mac for Development. Do you remember such a popup?

Comment: I do not remember seeing such a pop up.

Comment: Can't you just run a project without signing in? On a simulator? Then it might ask you...

Comment: I was able to build successfully with a simulator but I need to test Push Notifications and they don't work on simulators so it's a temporary win haha. Still need to be able to add an account so I can build to my device eventually. Thanks for the feedback though, gave me a reprieve from my frustration!

Comment: Ha well good luck with that!